# How-to Compass & flexbox: make it output all the legacy versions and prefixes?

Tags: sass, flexbox, compass-sass, compass

I had an issue with Safari, on pc, vers 5.1, and also Safari on Mac (unknown details).  So I'm trying to figure out what the most compatible flexbox display is.

I try this:

```
.d_flex_grid{
    @include flexbox(( display: flex ));
}
.d_flex_grid1{
    @include flexbox(( display: flex ), $version: 1);
}
.d_flex_grid2{
    @include flexbox(( display: flex ), $version: 2);
}
.d_flex_grid3{
    @include flexbox((display: flex), $version: 3);
}
```

I get this:

```
.d_flex_grid {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex; }

.d_flex_grid1 {
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex; }

.d_flex_grid2 {
  display: -ms-flex; }

.d_flex_grid3 {
  display: flex; }
```

What I want is https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/ :

```
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
```

Or something even more cross/legacy browser.  Is compass set up to do this, or should I roll my own?

Comment: Have you considered [**autoprefixer**](https://autoprefixer.github.io/)?

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to add another step to my flow, and also, it would be easier, on balance, to just roll my own flexbox() mixin.  I could have that done in a sec, but I'd like to keep with compass, as much as possible.  And also, there will be more like this, with the different parts of flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want (Compass >= 1):

```
.d_flex_grid {
  @include flexbox((display: box), $version: 1);
  @include flexbox((display: flexbox), $version: 2);
  @include display-flex;
}
```

Output:

```
.d_flex_grid {
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```